# Как дописать что-либо к последней строке файла

Tags: python, файлы

Есть цикл, на каждой итерации, найденные объекты записываются в файл, в конце цикла вычисляется время отработки скрипта и тоже записывается в файл:

```
start_time = time.time()
for j, box in enumerate(draw_boxes):
    ...
    f.write(f"{image_name_full} - {pred_classes[j]} - {score_percent}\n")

end_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
output_str = f"{image_name_full} - {pred_classes[j]} - {score_percent} - {elapsed_time:.2f}\n"
f.write(output_str)
```

Сейчас в файл записывается:

- test (151).jpg - JMEN_GREEN - 78%
- test (151).jpg - JMEN_GREEN - 73%
- test (151).jpg - KBB_WHITE - 72%
- test (151).jpg - KBB_ORANGE - 60%
- test (151).jpg - KBB_ORANGE - 60% - 11.44

Проблема в том, что последняя строка дублируется.
Как приписать время последней строчке, вместо её дублирования?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
start_time = time.time()
...
output_str = (f"{image_name_full} - {pred_classes[j]} - {score_percent}" for j, box in enumerate(draw_boxes))

end_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
f.write('\n'.join(output_str) + f" - {elapsed_time:.2f}\n")
```

Comment: *f-строки похоже не поддерживают обратные слешы, как одинарные, так и двойные.

Comment: Вы про print(f'\\')?

Comment: `f.write(f"{'\n'.join(output_str)} - {elapsed_time:.2f}\n")
                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash`

Comment: Просто join нужно сделать в строке `output_str =` вместо f-строки, заодно содержимое переменной станет соответствовать ее названию.

Comment: f.write('\n'.join(output_str) + f" - {elapsed_time:.2f}\n")

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
output_str = f"{image_name_full} - {pred_classes[j]} - {score_percent} - {elapsed_time:.2f}\n"
```

Написать

```
output_str = f"{elapsed_time:.2f}\n"
```

Comment: Но это допишется на следующей строке (новой последней строкой), а не в последней (непустой) строке, потому что в последней строке стоит перенос строки.

Comment: @insolor Можно попробовать сначала отрезать последний перевод строки: `f.seek(-len(os.linesep), 2)`

Comment: @CrazyElf можно, но не универсально, нужно точно знать тип символа переноса строки в файле

Comment: @insolor В смысле, он может быть другой, чем `os.linesep`? Каким образом? Насколько я понимаю, `\n` при выводе в текстовый файл преобразуется именно в `os.linesep`.

Comment: @CrazyElf ну, в данном случае по идее нет, но в целом может. Но в любом случае это довольно костыльно. Плюс могут быть всякие краевые случаи - например, исходно файл без переноса строки, а draw_boxes пустой.

Comment: @insolor Ладно, убедили. Лучше без костылей )